# my django mysql filter not woking am getting error message

Tags: django

am getting this error below

```
accountyp  = Customer.objects.values('accountyp').get(custid=cusid)
accouncode = Accountype.objects.values('accounttypecode').get(accountypename=accountyp)
```

am getting this error message Accountype matching query does not exist.

```
def generateacct(request,cusid):
    cusid=cusid
    
   
    accountyp = Customer.objects.values('accountyp').get(custid=cusid)
    accouncode= Accountype.objects.values('accounttypecode').get(accountypename=accountyp)

    return render(request,'generateacctno.html',accountyp)
```

Comment: Can you describe fields of 2 models: Customer and Accountype? Basically, when using Model.objects.get(field=value),  If there are no results that match the query, get() will raise a DoesNotExist exception